How to Completely localize VueJS dependencies on Azure DevOps artifacts?
I need to develop some Vue applications on a pc running on a private network that's not connected to the internet.
I've published all packages listed in package-lock.json to the Azure DevOps' Artifacts.
when I try
npm install vue

It's Ok and imports needed nodemodules to the directory but no app is created. but I need the Create function work
when I try:
npm create vue@latest

I get an error that 404 The package "create-vue" was not found in feed 'name of my feed'
I'm new to nodeJS. I need something like "pip download something" in python to get all packages needed. or if there is nothing like that in "NodeJS" just help me about this.
Best regards.

Package needed here is create-vue, install that one with NPM.

@kissu yes dude you're right. but my question is how to find and download all needed packages to create a vue project without internet

there is a tool named "download-tgz"
I've found a way to extract all dependency tree packages as tgz with this command:
download-tgz package-json /path/to/package.json --DevDependencies

I got most of dependent packages but let me know if you know a better way.
the best way for downloading all modules is:
download-tgz package @vue/cli --devDependencies --peerDependencies

I hope this help someone :)
